# TERASOLUNA Server Framework for Java（Web版）チュートリアル　最新版環境構築について

Tags: java

現在、TERASOLUNA Server Framework for Java（Web版）チュートリアルについての実装や調査を行っているのですが、下記の当初はチュートリアルの内容の通り

[2.2 チュートリアル学習環境の整備](http://terasoluna.osdn.jp/tutorial/server-web/Document/WebTutorial_2.2.html)

・Java SE 5.0
・Apache Tomcat 5.5
・H2 Database Engine 1.0
・Eclipse SDK 3.2.xx

のツールで操作や実装を行えました。

次はこのチュートリアルの操作を最新版でできないかという、試みをしているのですが
terasoluna-spring-thin-blankをインポート

画像のように
?アイコンが乱立してサーバー起動しても４０４エラーが返ってくる状態になってしまっています。
[image: terasoluna-spring-thin-blankプロジェクトをインポートした結果]

新しく設定してみた環境は、

・Java SE 8.0
・Apache Tomcat 9.0.0
・H2 Database Engine 1.0
・Pleiades All in One 4.7.0.v20170628
  Eclipse 4.7 Oxygen 0

のように変えています。

あくまでチュートリアルのバージョン通りに行えば順調にいきますが、
ツールを最新版に変えてカスタマイズした場合に、互換性の問題等があるのでしょうか？

何か考えられる要因があれば、教えていただきたいのですがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java SE 8.0は、それ以前のJava SEと互換性に問題があります。

非互換性についての詳しい説明は、以下の記事を参照してください。
[JDK 8の互換性ガイド](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/jp/java/javase/overview/8-compatibility-guide-2156366-ja.html#A999097)